# Geojson AJAX calls interfere with onEachFeature functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, geojson

The purpose of the map is when a user selects a HTML input it pulls a geojson file and places the zip code information on the map for that state. Then a second geojson file will pull the state bounds and also put it on the map and zoom to that state. Currently I am trying to accomplish this with two Geojson AJAX calls.   One is called `geojson` and the other is `statelay` (see below). When I just have the map run with only the `geojson` object it runs fine and the interaction with the zip codes runs smoothly. However, when I add `statelay` the interactivity no longer works with the first `geosjon` call. Here is what the interactivity looks like when it works: https://www.freepropertycalc.com/maps.

Here are the specific questions:

-Why does adding the `statelay` object below interfere with the interactivity of the other `geojson` call?
-How can I simply get the bounds from `statelay` and make the map zoom to those state bounds?

Code:

```
<select id="select"  >
    <option value="">State </option>
    <option value="{{url_for('static', filename= 'AK.js' )}}">AK</option>
    <option value="{{url_for('static', filename= 'AL.js' )}}">AL</option>
    <!-- a whole bunch more states -->
</select>
</div>


 <div id="map2" class = "content-section middle toppad" ></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var state = '/static/state.js';
var select = document.getElementById('select') ;


select.addEventListener('change', function(){
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
var strUser = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;


ourRequest.open('GET',select.value)
ourRequest.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('map2').innerHTML = "<div id='llmap'></div>";

    var TILE_URL = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    var MB_ATTR = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    map = L.map('llmap', {});

    L.tileLayer(TILE_URL, {attribution: MB_ATTR}).addTo(map);

 
   map.setView(new L.LatLng(38.500000, -98.000000), 4);


    function onLocationError(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}

    // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h6>Market Info by ZIP Code</h6>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' +  'ZIP: ' + props.ZIP + '</b><br />' + 
            'Median Home Property Value, May 2020: ' + props.valmay2020  + '<br />' +
            'Median Home Sale Price, March 2020: ' + props.salemarch2020 + '<br />' +
            'Median Rent, April 2020: ' + props.rentapr2020 + ', City Level Only' + '<br / >' +
            '1yr. House Value Change: ' + props.chg1yrpropval +'%' + '<br />' 
            : 'Hover over a ZIP Code');
    };

    info.addTo(map);


    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return d >  400000 ? '#800026' :
                d > 300000  ? '#BD0026' :
                d > 200000  ? '#E31A1C' :
                d > 150000  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                d > 100000   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                d > 50000   ? '#FEB24C' :
                d > 25000   ? '#FED976' :
                            '#FFEDA0';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.valmay2020)
        };
    }

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }

        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    var geojson;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            click: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            dbblick: zoomToFeature
        });
    }


var geojson = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(select.value, {
            style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

var statelay = new  L.GeoJSON.AJAX(state, {
        filter: statefilter
}).addTo(map);


function statefilter(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.STUSPS == strUser) return true
}

map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Housing and Rental data &copy; Zillow');


    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 25000, 50000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 300000, 400000],
            labels = [],
            from, to;

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i];
            to = grades[i + 1];
            froml = grades[i]/1000 + 'k';
            tol = grades[i +1]/1000 + 'k';

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                froml + (to ? '&ndash;' + tol : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
        return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);


};


ourRequest.send();

});
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can upload `state.js` file to https://www.freepropertycalc.com/maps so I can test your code

Comment: Thank you, I wlll be able to do that a bit later today and will notify you once it is up there.

Comment: I uploaded the file, the state file is in the maps directory and the file is located here https://www.freepropertycalc.com/static/state.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a easy fix.

1. Your interactivity is gone, because you add the state geojson over the interactivity geojson. Two solutions:

- call `statelay.bringToBack()` when you want to display the area / border
- don't add it to the map, if you don't want to show it. Remove `.addTo(map)` from `var statelay = new  L.GeoJSON.AJAX(...).addTo(map)`

2. Zoom to the bounds: Wait until the geojson is loaded and the call `fitBounds`

```
statelay.on('data:loaded', function() {
   map.fitBounds(statelay.getBounds())
})
```

But you will have a problem with zooming to the bounds for example with `AK`, because the shape is not correct (But that can't fixed by me):
[image: Wrong Shape]

And this is very lazy because this is a very big file ... so I recommand you a other way to zoom to the area:

zoom to the bounds of the `geojson` layer, then it is zoomed directly after the interactiv shapes are loaded.

```
geojson.on('data:loaded', function() {
    map.fitBounds(geojson.getBounds())
})
```

Comment: thank you!  I am new to mapping/web dev so if you have any handy resources for leaflet (besides for their wonderful website) that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know a other good website with leaflet code. Mostly I find all my leaflet questions here on SO

Comment: @Mike I found a solution to fix the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64386168/8283938 But I think you have to reverse the calculation: `if(coords[0] > 0){coords[0] = coords[0]-360}`